# Specified Text getting converted into icons while posting but doesnt do the same while receiving

Tags: php, jquery, preg-replace

I tried modifying a chat script.
(The [original script](http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/entry/ajax-auto-refresh-volume-ii) is from Eliza Witkowska link.) I mainly tried converting some text into emoticons. So far I can only convert text into emoticons properly.

But, the text gets converted to icons only when I send the message but doesn't get converted when I receive the message on another browser (I'm using sessions so I have to use another browser) unless a refresh or I send a message from that another browser.

To be more clear, suppose I have logged in to an a/c from chrome and another a/c from Firefox; when I send a message from Chrome, the specified characters get converted into icons but only the characters show up on firefox until a page refresh or until a new message is sent from firefox.

db.php

```
function check_changes(){
    $result = $this->db->query('SELECT counting FROM news WHERE id=1');
    if($result = $result->fetch_object()){
        return $result->counting;
    }
    return 0;
}


function get_news(){
    if($result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM news WHERE id<>1 ORDER BY add_date DESC LIMIT 50')){
        $return = '';
        while($r = $result->fetch_object()){
            $timing=explode(" ", $r->add_date);

            $return .= $r->title;
            $return .='<p>'.$timing[1].' on '.$timing[0].'</p><hr/> ';
            //$return .= '<hr/>';
        }
        return $return;
    }
}
```

profile.php

```
function parseSmiley($text){
    //Smiley to image
    $smileys=array('o:)'=>'angel.gif', ':3'=>'colonthree.gif', 'o.O'=>'confused.gif', ":'("=>'cry.gif', '3:)'=>'devil.gif', ':('=>'frown.gif', ':O'=>'gasp.gif', '8)'=>'glasses.gif', ':D'=>'grin.gif', ">:("=>'grumpy.gif', '<3'=>'heart.gif', '^_^'=>'kiki.gif', ':*'=>'kiss.gif', ':v'=>'pacman.gif', ':)'=>'smile.gif', '-_-'=>'squint.gif', '8|'=>'sunglasses.gif', ':p'=>'tongue.gif', ':/'=>'unsure.gif', '>:O'=>'upset.gif', ';)'=>'wink.gif');

    //Now you need to find and replace
    foreach($smileys as $smiley=>$img){
        $smiley = preg_quote($smiley, '/');
        $text = preg_replace( "#(?<=\s|^)(?:$smiley)((?=\s|$))?#i", '<img src="emotions-fb/'.$img.'">', $text);
    }
    //Now only return it
    return $text;
}

$print= parseSmiley($db->get_news());


<div id="message_short" data-counter="<?php echo (int)$db->check_changes();?>">
<?php echo wordwrap($print, 25, "\n", true);?>
</div>
<div id="message_long" data-counter="<?php echo (int)$db->check_changes();?>">
<?php echo wordwrap($print, 35, "\n", true);?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to wrap `get_news()` everywhere with `parseSmiley()`.

As I can see from the link provided, there is a `checker.php` in which `$db->get_news()` should be replaced with `parseSmiley($db->get_news())`

Comment: Perfect! It worked. Just one more thing, I have removed htmlspecialchars from get_news function. Will it be a problem? And how should I get a button to load previous messages just like the chat in stackoverflow?

Comment: htmlspecialchars() makes sure (to some extend) no html or javascript can be injected into someone elses browser. This should be left in, because it can prevent someone from getting cookies of a different user for example. Type htmlspecialchars into google to find more on the subject.

Comment: Concerning the button, please try first for yourself... I can help you along, but I havent got time to do it for you ;)

Comment: Ok..I will try myself but if you could give me some hints on how to go about. :)

Comment: You should make function which is able to load a certain amount of items with an offset from the database. The offset should be the id of the first or last newsitem shown (depending on your needs). The amount is the maximum amount of newsitems to load up in 1 go. You also need a new ajax-call to use this function (and bind it to a new click event).

Comment: By default this script calls the last 50 entries and hides the rest forever.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64046/discussion-between-ayan-and-richardbernards).